# R filling zeros with mean value

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have this table right now that looks like this:

```
Worker | Score
A      | 10
A      | 20
A      | 0
A      | 0
A      | 0
B      | 2
B      | 4
B      | 0
B      | 6
```

Right now some of my scores which are unavailable I've filled them with 0. Is there a way on R where I can replace those 0 values with the mean value of the particular worker's score. The final table should look like this:

```
Worker | Score
A      | 10
A      | 20
A      | 15 (mean of other scores)
A      | 15 (mean of other scores)
A      | 15 (mean of other scores)
B      | 2
B      | 4
B      | 4 (mean of other scores)
B      | 6
```

Right now I am thinking of looping through but I have 100 of thousands of entries which would make it very slow and inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ave` to find the averages for each `Worker` and then use `replace` to substitute the relevant values

```
replace(x = df$Score, list = df$Score == 0, values =
  ave(df$Score, df$Worker, FUN = function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(x!=0))[df$Score == 0])
#[1] 10 20 15 15 15  2  4  4  6
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(Worker = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B"), Score = c(10L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 6L)), .Names = c("Worker", 
"Score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is `na.aggregate` from `base R`.  Replace the 0 values in 'score' by NA, grouped by 'Worker', apply the `na.aggregate` on 'Score' to replace the 'NA' by the `mean` of the 'Score' by assigning it to 'Score'

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df1)[Score ==0, Score := NA ][, .(Score = na.aggregate(Score)), by = Worker]
#   Worker Score
#1:      A    10
#2:      A    20
#3:      A    15
#4:      A    15
#5:      A    15
#6:      B     2
#7:      B     4
#8:      B     4
#9:      B     6
```

---

Or it can be made more compact by

```
setDT(df1)[, .(Score = na.aggregate(Score*NA^!Score)), Worker]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Worker = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B"), Score = c(10L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 6L)),
.Names = c("Worker", 
"Score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with `data.table`

```
library("data.table")
df1 <- data.table(Worker = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
                  Score = c(10L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 6L))
m <- df1[Score!=0, mean(Score), Worker]
m[df1, on="Worker"][, `:=`(Score=ifelse(Score==0, V1, Score), V1=NULL)][]
```